# Splicing price from amount on concatenated string

Tags: c#, regex

I was working on a POS system. This version would replace an existing version currently in use. The version in use was programmed in Visual Basic and has loads of now obsolete and unused classes and screens, whereas this new version will use Visual C# (WinForms). I was looking for a way to get the receipts into a List (where product contains name, price and amount). However, the older receipts were stored into a single databasecell as follows:

```
Title of product A&amp;euro; 449,001&amp;euro; 449,00Title of product B&amp;euro; 14.2&amp;euro; 28.00Title of product C€0.52 €1Title of product D€220 €40
```

So far, I've been able to slice these into single strings of one product using `Regex.Replace(text, @"(€\d*.?\d{0,2})\s*(\d+)\s*(€\d*.\d{0,2})", "${0}↨")` and slicing afterwards (which could be done within one go probably, but I find this more clear) with

```
string pattern = "(.*?)↨";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    stringList.Add(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Which would then result in a List of strings containing [Title, price/per item , amount and total price for this item]:

```
Title of product A€449,001 €449,00
Title of product B€14.2 €28.00
Title of product C€0.52 €1
Title of product D€220 €40
```

I then use (assume product is declared)

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(oneProductText, @"(.*?)€(\d*.?\d{0,2})\s*([1-9]+\d*)\s*€(\d*.\d{0,2})↨");
        //text - price/per - amount - price total || use after broken into pieces.
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            product = new DCKKassa.Product();
            product.name = match.Groups[1].Value;
            product.price = Decimal.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            product.amount = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
        }
```

Which will work for most strings to product conversions, however there are some corner cases that are not handled. I was looking for a way to handle those.
Strings containing:

```
€.011   €0.01  - handled
€1.001  €1.00  - handled
€1.01   €1.00  - handled
€11     €1.00  - handled
€1.0011 €11.00 - handled
€1.010  €11.00 - handled
€1.011  €11.00 - UNHANDLED will result in €1.01 being handled 1 time
€1.11   €11.00 - UNHANDLED will result in €1.10 being handled 1 time
€112    €12.00 - UNHANDLED will result in €11 being handled 2 times
etc.
```

**So what I'm struggling with is that I was looking for a way to get `€1.011 €11.00` to split in `€1.0 | 11 | €11.00.`**
I was thinking of taking the latter price, and trying to find the right cut between the first euro-amount combination such that firstEuro * amount results in the second amount. However, I was wondering if there was some hidden (well at least for me) feature in Regex to handle such a thing.

I would love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered running it through `HtmlDecode` to change the encoded euro symbol in to the actual character?  Then you shoudl easily be able to split it on the `;` delimiter. It looks like it might need multiple passes.

Comment: Actually, looking at your example data more closely, I'm not sure how it is supposed to be delimited.  There doesn't seem to be any separator between fields.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I guess I had an error in there. I have gotten to the point where i changed the `&amp;euro;` to an euro sign. I was now looking at how to get the price per piece of a product and amounts of product that were bought. I will edit my question for clarity.

Comment: How do you want to handle the ambiguity in that `€1.011` could be `€1.0 | 11` or `€1.01 | 1`?

Comment: @BradleyUffner well, the last price is like the "total" price for that product, so price per piece times the amount that product is bought. So yeah I'm guessing the only way is to "guess" the cut and check if its right, and if its not then you have to move the cut one digit and check again, continuing till its right

Comment: So its either `€1.0 | 11 | €11.00` or `€1.01 | 1 | €1.01`

Comment: Ahh, I see.  If that is the case, then RegEx isn't the right tool to parse that.  You will probably need to loop through the decimal digits of the first number group, pulling off one number at a time from the right side, and testing the math to see if it works out.  You could use regex to break it in to the basic groups, but it won't be able to solve breaking the total and quantity without a fixed delimiter.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, Thank you, Will do that.

Comment: Also, track down the person who came up with that data format, and give them a nice strong thwacking.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes haha, I was planning on using `Product` in JSON format for the new app.

Comment: If you have a choice, I'd lean towards a proper relational format in the database instead of a flat field.  Something like `Order` with customer and total information, and `OrderDetail` with individual line item information, like item#, price, quantity.

Comment: Yeah, If I'd had the choice I would've. Unfortunatelly I do not, have to keep using the same database. So I'll just place JSON in the holder column.

Comment: The first thing to do is to follow @BradleyUffner advice about thwacking the original coder. Then you will feel much more relaxed and the solution will magically come out without any effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I went down the road of grabbing the price/amount concat and trying until I found the proper cut. For me:

```
private Product getProduct(string oneProductText)
    {
        Product product = new Product();
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(oneProductText, @"(.*?)€(\d*.?\d{0,2}\s*[1-9]+\d*)\s*€(\d*.\d{0,2})↨");
        //text - price/per - amount - price total || use after broken into pieces.

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            product = new Product();
            product.name = match.Groups[1].Value;
            decimal totalPrice = Decimal.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            decimal[] priceAndAmount = getPricePerAndAmount(match.Groups[2].Value, totalPrice);
            product.price = priceAndAmount[0];
            product.amount = (int)priceAndAmount[1];
        }
        return product;
    }
private decimal[] getPricePerAndAmount(string priceAmount, decimal totalPrice)
    {
        decimal[] priceAndAmount = new decimal[2];
        for (int i = 1; i <= priceAmount.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            decimal amount = Decimal.Parse(Right(priceAmount, i), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            decimal price = Decimal.Parse(priceAmount.Substring(0, priceAmount.Length - i), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            decimal tempPrice = amount * price;

            if (totalPrice == tempPrice)
            {
                priceAndAmount[0] = price;
                priceAndAmount[1] = amount;
                break;
            }
        }
        return priceAndAmount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        {
            string input = "Title of product A&amp;euro; 449,001&amp;euro; 449,00Title of product B&amp;euro; 14.2&amp;euro; 28.00Title of product C&amp;euro; €0.52 €1Title of product D&amp;euro; €220 €40";
            string pattern = "(?'title'Title of product [A-Z]+)&amp;(?'currency'[^;]+);\\s+(?'value'[€0-9,\\. ]+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input,pattern);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("title = '{0}', currency = '{1}', value = '{2}' ", match.Groups["title"].Value, match.Groups["currency"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```